# Is there a way to query on parts of a date in a `find` query in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

so I know I can do this with an aggregate operation, but I'm not sure if I'm missing something as I can't seem to do it with a simple `find` call. For example I tried:

```
{'CreationTime': { '$dayOfMonth': 26 }}
```

But that failed with: `unknown operator: $dayOfMonth`.

I think I can achieve this with an `$in` query but that feels ugly having to generate every possible date.

Is this possible with a regular `find` query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer:  No it is not.

`find()` only supports (as of v5) a small subset of functions that can be applied to fields compared to `aggregate()`.  For some years now, `aggregate` is the new `find`.  Under almost all conditions there is no performance benefit to using `find` but for simple expressions it is clearly more compact and convenient.

And starting with v4.4, many tricky `update` expressions are handled easier through `aggregate` with the `merge` stage set to the *same* collection as the input.

Comment: Thanks, and also for pre-empting my next question about why use `find` at all!